# Where is my mistake in this integral equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I'm given the equation $$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=Ae^{-x}+\int_{0}^{x}G(y)e^{-(x-y)}dy$$

for $0<x<\tilde{x}$ and $A$ is constant

The question require to find $f$ (the integral on y doesn't have to be solved)

It appears that the final answer is

$$f(\tilde{x})-f(0)=A(1-e^{-\tilde{x}})+\int_{0}^{\tilde{x}}G(y)(1-e^{-(\tilde{x}-y)})dy$$

My question why is it not goes like that:
$$f(\tilde{x})-f(0)=A(1-e^{-\tilde{x}})+\int_{0}^{\tilde{x}}G(y)e^{y}dy\int_{0}^{\tilde{x}}e^{-x}dx$$

$$=f(\tilde{x})-f(0)=A(1-e^{-\tilde{x}})+\int_{0}^{\tilde{x}}G(y)e^{y}(1-e^{-\tilde{x}})dy$$

I don't understand why my answer is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your solution, it appears you are integrating both sides from $0$ to $\tilde{x}$. Just be careful because for the second term the integration interval depends on $x$; thus, you can't just integrate and switch the order of integration. In general,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\tilde{x}}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}h(x,y)dy\right)dx \neq \int_{a(\tilde{x})}^{b(\tilde{x})}\left( \int_{0}^{\tilde{x}}h(x,y)dx\right)dy\end{align}
My suggestion would be to differentiate both sides of the original equation and use Leibniz integral rule. You will obtain the following differential equation:
\begin{align}
 \frac{df(x)}{dx} = G(x) -  \frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}
\end{align}

Now you can safely integrate both sides and use the original equation to reach the correct answer:
\begin{align}
 f(\tilde{x}) - f(0) &= \int_{0}^{\tilde{x}}G(y)dy -  f'(\tilde{x}) + f'(0) \\
 &= \int_{0}^{\tilde{x}}G(y)dy - Ae^{-\tilde{x}}-\int_{0}^{\tilde{x}}G(y)e^{-(\tilde{x}-y)}dy + A \\ 
& = A(1-e^{-\tilde{x}}) + \int_{0}^{\tilde{x}}G(y)(1-e^{-(\tilde{x}-y)})dy.
\end{align}

Comment: im not sure i understood how I can get the correct answer from the last equation you wrote. can you explain please?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the Laplace Transform

$$
s\hat f(s) = \frac{A}{s+1}+\hat G(s)\frac{1}{s+1}+ f_0
$$

or

$$
\hat f(s) = \left(\frac 1s-\frac{1}{s+1}\right)A+\left(\frac 1s-\frac{1}{s+1}\right)\hat G(s) + \frac{f_0}{s}
$$

and anti-transforming we have

$$
f(x) = (1-e^{-x})A+\int_0^x G(\zeta)d\zeta - \int_{0}^{x}G(y)e^{-(x-y)}dy + f_0
$$